# Finding the root of a function through the bisection method

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that find the root of a function through the bisection method. I've watched a tutorial about it but I can't get their code to work.

This is the code I have:

```
import numpy as np

import sys

def min_bisect(func, a, b, error_accept): 

    def f(x):
        f = eval(func)
        return f
    
    error = abs(b - a)
    
    while error > error_accept:
        
        c =(b + a)/2
        
        if f(a) * f(b) >= 0:
            print("no roots present")
            sys.exit()
            
        elif f(c) * f(a) < 0:
            b = c 
            error * abs(b - a)
            
        elif f(c) * f(b) < 0:
            a = c 
            error * abs(b - a)
            
        else:
            print("something went wrong")
            sys.exit()
            
    print("the error is " , error )
    print("the lower boudary, a, is " , a , ". the upper boundary is b, is " , b)
  
    
min_bisect("np.exp(x)-(4*x)" , 0 , 1 , (0.0001))
```

And I'm getting the "something went wrong" message, it seems like it never enters the if or the elif statements.

How could I solve this?

Comment: as an aside, you shouldn't do this with eval. Just *pass a function*, then you can just use `func(a) * func(b)` etc. So `min_bisect(lambda np.exp(x) - (4*x)", 0, 1, (0.0001))`

Comment: Think about what this line does: `error * abs(b - a)`. Does it change anything?

Comment: `f(a) * f(b) >= 0` doesn't imply that no roots are present, just that the bisection method doesn't directly apply.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by juanpa.arrivillaga, you should not be using `eval`, but directly using a function:

```py
def func(x):
    return np.exp(x) - (4*x)
```

for instance.

If you print what is happening in your test case, with the values of `f(a)`, `f(b)` and `f(c)`, you will see that `f(c) = 0.0`, which is not a case handled by your algorithm, hence the error.
Also, you are not updating the `error` variable, so in almost any other case, you would get stuck on in an infinite loop.
Instead of

> `error * abs(b - a)`

which doesn't do anything, you probably want to update the error:
`error = abs(b - a)`.

There is also no need to use `sys.exit()`, you can probably directly `return` for instance

All in all, this should look like:

```py
def min_bisect(f, a, b, error_accept): 
    
    error = abs(b - a)
    
    while error > error_accept:
        
        c =(b + a)/2
        
        if f(a) * f(b) >= 0:
            print("no roots present")
            return
            
        elif f(c) * f(a) <= 0:
            b = c 
            error = abs(b - a)
            
        elif f(c) * f(b) < 0:
            a = c 
            error = abs(b - a)
            
        else:
            print("something went wrong")
            return
    print("the error is " , error )
    print("the lower boundary, a, is " , a , ". the upper boundary is b, is " , b)

min_bisect(lambda x: np.exp(x)-(4*x) , 0 , 1 , (0.0001))
```

You could also add a condition to check if `f(a)`, `f(b)` is 0 at the initialisation, and if `f(c)` is 0 at each iteration, as an optimisation.